# I am getting a Cannot find symbol error that I can't resolve

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am getting this error that to me looks like I am not calling the method correctly. I have reviewed the past answers here but none have specifically addressed my problem as far as I can see. This is for a class project. I realize my math in the method is most likely not correct yet but I need to get the rest working then deal with an incorrect out put. Thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrintOutNumbersInReverse {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Gather Number
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 2 and 10 digits long ");
        int num = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("your number is: " + num);

        // call method
        System.out.println("Your number in reverse is: " + reverse);

    }

    public static int reverse(int num, int rNum) {
        rNum = 0;
        while (num != 0) {
            rNum = rNum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

And My error Message:

> PrintOutNumbersInReverse.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
>       System.out.println ("Your number in reverse is: " +reverse);
>                                                          ^   symbol:   variable reverse   location: class PrintOutNumbersInReverse 1 error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `reverse` is a method - you're using it as if it's a variable. (Also, it doesn't return anything at the moment, and it's not clear why it would take two parameters...) Also, your code is very hard to read at the moment - please put a bit more effort into formatting your code before you hit Post.

Comment: Like @JonSkeet said, you should look in to [understanding methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I apologize for the code, this is only the 6 or 7th program I have ever written. So, if I am using it wrong, how should it be called. I have attempted to do it as shown in our book but am obviously missing something.

Comment: Look closely at the example code. Case-sensitive, and look at parentheses, and variables. Sometimes it may look like to you your code is the same, but it actually isn't. So look _closely_. And also, if you are just starting, _question everything_ until you understand what it does and how it does it. Thats my best advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change method implementation to:

```
public static int reverse (int num)
{

 int rNum = 0;
 ...

 return rNum;
}
```

and place, that is calling this method to:

```
System.out.println ("Your number in reverse is: " +reverse(num));
```

Then should be fine

Comment: Thank you very much Mateusz(and everyone else)! That made it work and now I just need to fix my math.Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

When copy pasting this into eclipse, i noticed 2 things:

1.) your `reverse()` method doesn't return an int, but it should because the signature of the method says so: `public static` **`int`** `reverse(int num, int rNum)`. Maybe return `rNum`, or whatever the logic behind it might be?

2.) second, you have not declared any `reverse` variable in the `main` method. Maybe you wanted a parameterized call of `reverse()`?

Also it looks like, you want in the `reverse()` method `rNum` to be an output parameter. In java you can't pass primitives by reference, so whatever you do with `rNum` inside the method, the changes will only be present in the scope of the method. So you might want to calculate something and actually `return` the results of your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `reverse` as a method, and not a variable. Also, you are passing in a variable that is not used: `rNum`. You see in `reverse(int num, int rNum);` right after you start, it sets your `rNum` to 0. So why pass a number in that will get set to zero?

I did this from my phone, but this should be working code:

```
 import java.util.*;

public class PrintOutNumbersInReverse {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Gather Number
       System.out.print("Enter a number between 2 and 10 digits long ");
       int num = console.nextInt();

       System.out.println("your number is: " + num);

       // call method
       System.out.println("Your number in reverse is: " + reverse(num)); //<-- notice how this is a method cause it has "()"

 }

public static int reverse(int num) {  //<-- this has "int num" in the "()". This is a parameter.  
    int rNum = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        rNum = rNum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Binghammer, I had tried a lot of combinations like this, but now that you show it I understand it much better.